# Return needed info from in while else

Tags: php, if-statement, while-loop

I have a problem with my code; I'm trying to compare informations from my database between the logged user and the rest of registered users, columns `time1`, `time2` and `time3`. Everything seems to work fine except for the else condition, I want to check only if the results are not the same in all the 3 columns. Here's my code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` != '$logged_id'");

if(!mysql_num_rows($result)) echo "None";
else {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $username = $row['username'];
        $time1 = $row['time1'];
        $time2 = $row['time2'];
        $time3 = $row['time3'];

        $times_array = array($time1, $time2, $time3);
        foreach ($times_array as $time_key => $time_value) {
            if($logged_time1 == $time_value || $logged_time2 == $time_value || $logged_time3 == $time_value) {
                echo $username . " at time " . $time_value;
            }
            elseif($logged_time1 != $time_value && $logged_time2 != $time_value && $logged_time3 != $time_value) {
                echo "no results";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should do that kind of filtering in your SQL query already …

Comment: Just pointing the obvious: `mysql*` functions are deprecated (see http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) and you should use PDO instead. Your code is open to SQL injections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think @CBroe was right. Just do your filtering in the SQL query like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` 
WHERE `time1` = '$logged_time1'
AND `time2` = '$logged_time2'
AND `time3` = '$logged_time3'
");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking at relational databases the wrong way. It would be best practice to have a separate table that stores times with a foreign key to a userID. Have a userID and a time. Then you can query that database for best times or narrow it down to a specific user and query their best times. Then you can use the following code:

```
SELECT * FROM times WHERE id='someUser' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 3;
```

or to get the best times of all time, simply use:

```
SELECT * FROM times ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 3;
```

and from there you can determine that the values are unique by using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT times ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 3;
```

or if you must keep it in one table, you can check distinct values using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT time_1,time_2, time_3
FROM table_name;
```